# How to nest repeater inside HTML table row with runat="server"

Tags: .net, webforms

In .NET web forms, I have quite a complex user control.  One of the features in this control is a table.  Using JavaScript, I need to be able to dynamically hide/show rows within this table.  I also need to be able to set row visibility on page load in .NET.  So I have attempted to add a `runat="server"` tag to the table row and give it an ID to satisfy both requirements.

However, when I do this, it breaks the model binding in the repeater - `Item is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr> <!-- Ignore, I have extra rows here that I need to be able to show/hide as well -->
        <tr></tr>
        <tr runat="server" ID="testID">
            <td runat="server" ID="incrementalSalesCell">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotalIncrementalSalesTitle" Text="Incremental Sales"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptGlobalIncrementalSales" ItemType="GlobalSalesControl">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIncrementalSalesYear1" Text='<%#Item.IncrementalSalesYear1%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIncrementalSalesYear2" Text='<%#Item.IncrementalSalesYear2%>'></asp:Label></td>
                    <td runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIncrementalSalesYear3" Text='<%#Item.IncrementalSalesYear3%>'></asp:Label></td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have used the `PlaceHolder` control successfully server side, but obviously the PlaceHolder only works server side, as it is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr></tr> <!-- Ignore, I have extra rows here that I need to be able to show/hide as well -->
    <tr></tr>
    <tr runat="server" ID="testID">
        <td runat="server" ID="incrementalSalesCell">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotalIncrementalSalesTitle" Text="Incremental Sales"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptGlobalIncrementalSales" ItemType="GlobalSalesControl">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= getYear(1);%>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= getYear(2);%>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td runat="server"><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= getYear(3);%>'></asp:Label></td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
   protected string getYear(int number)
    {

       switch (number)
       {
        case 1:
               return X;

        case 2:
              return Y;

        case 3:
              return Z;

        default:
              return W;
       }

   }
```

In page load, calculate the values to return (global vars X, Y, Z and W) to getYear function.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Adding runat="server" to the tr tag breaks the repeater.

There are some different ways you could solve this. You could use Javascript and CSS to hide it on the client side.

If you want to do it server side (on Page_Load), instead of hiding the row itself, hide its contents. It's a kludge, but it works.

If you're using a table with alternating colors for the rows, like the Bootstrap 'table-striped' class, you will end up with two rows of the same color next to each other when the contents are hidden because the row has no height but it's still there. To fix that, add an empty row and show it when you're hiding the other stuff, and vice versa.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td runat="server" ID="tdId" Visible='<%# RowIsVisible() %>'>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblWhatever" Text="Whatever"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptId" Visible='<%# RowIsVisible() %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    ...
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="trStripeFixer" Visible='<%# !RowIsVisible() %>'></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```